# Why does the command prompt showing this following error?

Tags: windows, command-prompt

I just installed the GCC compiler and wanted to test if it is working correctly. But in the middle, I am facing this issue with the command prompt as shown in the figure. 'ls' ie., List command is not working what might be the problem??

Regards,[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out Linux terminal commands and their Windows equivalents *instead of 'ls'* go for '**DIR**' which is the MS DOS version of LS, which lists the files and folders in the current directory

if you want to go for gcc then i think you should Install Cygwin, Install a set of Cygwin packages required for building GCC, From within Cygwin, download the GCC source code, build and install it, Test the new GCC compiler in C++14 mode using the -std=c++14 option
you could integrate GCC x64 on Windows with excellent new CLION IDE made by JetBrains.
or Alternatively you can get pre-built binaries using the MinGW-64 installer that lets you pick the flavor of GCC.

Answer (score 1):

`ls` is not a valid command in Windows. For listing all the directories and files in a directory, `dir` should be used instead.